# Files missing after switching from Google Filestream to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-file-stream

I was using Google Filestream to work on my laptop for years. I could open documents locally, edit them, save them, etc. And those folders and files would then sync to the cloud. I could open them in real time on my laptop. Today, I didn't seem to have a choice but to switch to Google Drive. I thought nothing much would change. Now, all my work files are no longer stored locally on my laptop. I have to go into Google Drive via a browser and either download the file I want to work on or try to work with Google apps. This is a complete disaster and I literally cannot work like this.

How can I either undo this change or set up a system as I had before, i.e. I can open a word document (or whatever) locally and work on it locally. Then when I save it, the change is synced to the cloud.

[image]
These are the only 2 options. I assumed I would have offline access. But now there are more than 50gb of folders in the cloud that I cannot access via Windows Explorer. When it said "store all My Drive files in the cloud and on your computer", I assumed I would have local access. But I don't.

How can I make Google Drive folders and files available offline so that I can work on them via Windows Explorer?

Comment: In case I wasn't clear, I need to be able to access everything through Windows Explorer. I want to cut out the middleman (Google Chrome browser)

Comment: [It appears you could have delayed the upgrade until August 18 2021](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2021/07/google-drive-backup-and-sync-transition.html?m=1)

Comment: I edited the question. My entire research project was available in Windows Explorer before today and that is how I worked on it. Now it is entirely in the cloud and I can only access it via a browser. Are you saying I have to download the entire cloud contents to my laptop?

Comment: You say "verify what folder has been configured" but I only have the option to add folders from my laptop that I want synced TO the cloud. I don't have an option to select a cloud folder that I want to be made available offline

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed the desktop client for Google Drive? https://www.google.com/intl/en-GB/drive/download/ Look for the download text next to "For Individuals"

Comment: You may [Use Google Drive files offline](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375012?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop).

Comment: @harrymc - [Google is moving away from `Backup and Sync` to `Drive for desktop` so the author actually wants the download that is currently marked for "teams".](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2021/07/google-drive-backup-and-sync-transition.html?m=1)

Answer (score 2):

This was a false alarm. I will delete the question.

When I switched over to Google Drive, it removed all the available folders from local access. Immediately after installation those folders were not available. After letting the program run overnight, it eventually synced them again and the folders are now visible and usable via Windows Explorer. I was panicking.

When you switch over, don't panic. Allow Google Drive several hours to sync if you have a large volume of material you need access to.